# Solr Query Parse Exception

Tags: solr

I have string `str="cooper"s towm"` and want to escape the double quote inside the string(char after r).
I am using `str.replaceAll("\"","\\\"");` but while executing query in solr, still it is throwing parse exception.

Please help to resolve it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a backslash.

```
str.replaceAll("\"","\\"");
```

should be

```
str.replaceAll("\"","\\\\\"");
```